# Как суммировать общее количество времени

Tags: php, javascript, html

значение в переменных такое "13 minutes 34 seconds", "14 seconds"," 5 minutes 26 seconds"

как мне посчитать общее количество времени, PHP, Javascript

Comment: еще может быть и ЧАС "18 hours 33 minutes 27 seconds"

Comment: Может с помощью регулярки, парсить число перед словом и соответственно предпренимать соответствующие действия

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$DATE_1  = new DateTime('NOW');
$DATE_2  = clone $DATE_1;
$ARRAY   = [
    "13 minutes 34 seconds",
    "12 seconds",
    "5 minutes 26 seconds"
];
foreach ($ARRAY as $value)
{
    $DATE_2->modify($value);
}
$DIFF = date_diff($DATE_1, $DATE_2);
var_dump($DIFF);
```

Дальше работаем с `$DIFF`.

Comment: чет мне кажется вы дали не правильный ответ, извини, но я очень плохо знаю php

Comment: object(DateInterval)#5 (8) { ["y"]=> int(0) ["m"]=> int(0) ["d"]=> int(0) ["h"]=> int(0) ["i"]=> int(19) ["s"]=> int(12) ["invert"]=> int(0) ["days"]=> int(0) }

Comment: @ШкедАскет Ну? Вы получили `DateInterval` с английским чтоль тоже плохо? http://php.net/manual/ru/class.dateinterval.php - документация. Если вам нужно общее кол-во секунд, то: `var_dump($DIFF)` меняем на: `var_dump($DATE_2->getTimestamp() - $DATE_1->getTimestamp())`

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ! и извините, что потревожил

Answer (score 0):

гугл дает вот такой ответ,

time=06:58:00, time2=00:40:00, result = 07:38:00

```
$time = "06:58:00"; 
$time2 = "00:40:00";
$secs = strtotime($time2)-strtotime("00:00:00");
$result = date("H:i:s",strtotime($time)+$secs);
```

Comment: как формат времени поменять тогда)?